# Insert with PHP and AngularJs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

So, I'm new to AngularJS and I was trying to do a simple web page to add values to a MySQL database with PHP. Here is the HTML:

```
<DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="pt">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pannel.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pannel.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Garagi Extreme</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Inserir Carro</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Alterar/excluir Carro</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Inserir Montadora</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Alterar/excluir Montadora</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
</nav>
<div ng-app="garagem" ng-controller="montadora">
  <form>
    <p>Nome da Montadora: <input type="text" ng-model="nomeMont"/></p>
    <input type="button" ng-click="insertMontadora()" value="Enviar" class="btn primary-btn"/>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And My pannel.js:

```
var app= angular.module('garagem', []);
app.controller('montadora',["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.insertMontadora=function () {
$http.post("db/insertMont.php", {'nomeMont': $scope.nomeMont})
.success(function (data,status,headers,config) {
  console.log("Inserted");
});
}
}]);
```

And my PHP page to connect to the database and make the query:

```
$nomeMont=mysql_real_escape_string($data->nomeMont);

$local_server="localhost";
$usuario= "tkc";
$senha="185478";
$banco="garagiextrem";

mysql_connect($local_server, $usuario, $senha) or die("Nope");
mysql_select_db($banco) or die("Nain");
mysql_query('INSERT INTO montadora(idMontadora,Nome) VALUES ("NULL",'" . $nomeMont . "')');
 ?>
```

When I load the page on a browser, everything works just fine, and I even get the "Inserted" message on the console. But when I go check the phpMyAdmin, there is no entries on the table.
What am I doing wrong here? :(

Comment: You're not checking the success or failure of `mysql_query` (or other function calls). Try checking for errors rather than assuming everything just works. Also, you should use `mysqli` since `mysql` is depreciated and will be removed from future releases of php.

Comment: For the mysql instead of mysqli or PDO, I'm following an old tutorial, apparently XD. But could you tell me how can I check for this errors in the query? Sorry, I'm a noob, haha

Comment: Write out mysql errors to at text file. Maybe there is an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check for any errors backend you can send the result and display an appropriate message within Angular.

The below php code uses `mysqli` functions and checks for errors that may arise.

Assuming `idMontadora` is the primary key of your table and it is auto incrementing, you don't need to include it in the insert query.

I would recommend using output buffering because any notices will dirty the json returned to Angular. See the use of `ob_start()` at the top of the script, and `ob_clean()` immediately before the json is echoed.

I have written a little function to handle the echo of the result `process_output()` to avoid code duplication.

```
<?php
// start output buffering
ob_start();

// utility function to clean output and echo as json
function process_output($result, $msg)
{
    $out = array('result' => $result, 'msg' => $msg);
    ob_clean();
    echo json_encode($out, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    exit();
}

$local_server="localhost";
$usuario= "tkc";
$senha="185478";
$banco="garagiextrem";
// setup mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli($local_server, $usuario, $senha, $banco);
// check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    process_output(0, "Connect failed: ".$mysqli->connect_error);
// define the query
$sql ="INSERT INTO montadora (Nome) VALUES (?)";
// prepare the query
if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) 
    process_output(0, "Prepare failed: ".$stmt->error);
// bind the parameter
if (!$res = $stmt->bind_param('s', $data->nomeMont))
    process_output(0, "Bind failed: ".$stmt->error);
// execute
if (!$res = $stmt->execute())
    process_output(0, "Execute failed: ".$stmt->error);
// no errors so return true
process_output(1, "Rows inserted: ".$stmt->affected_rows);
```

In your Angular controller you can then use the result to debug what is happening backend, and also to display an appropriate message to the user, etc.

The below just console logs the data received from the `$http.post`, but you can extend it to handle the success or error appropriately.

```
var app= angular.module('garagem', []);
app.controller('montadora',["$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.insertMontadora=function () {
        $http.post("db/insertMont.php", {'nomeMont': $scope.nomeMont}).then(
            function (data,status,headers,config) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
                console.log(status);
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

The backend sends the `msg` which tells you what has happened, and the `result` key that can be easily used to setup error handling in the controller. Eg. `if (data.result === 0) { // handle the error }`